# Composite element isn't working

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm trying to follow this tutorial by Matthew O'Phinney but not getting anywhere.

http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/217-Creating-composite-elements.html

All I'm trying to do is create a composite element that consists of a checkbox and an input text.

```
new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox();
new Zend_Form_Element_Text()
```

The code I have got too complicated with lots of commenting in and out but nothing's working. I'm sure it's easier than this, but I seem to be on the wrong track.

Comment: You need to be specific about what your actual problem is

Comment: Why do you need a composite element though? Why can't you just have both as separate elements in your form? As for Mathews approach - you definitely need a decorator - I can't think how else you could render it otherwise. In Mathew's example, he creates a decorator that calls view helpers for each of the child element components - in that way he can place those elements within the surrounding markup exactly where he needs them.  Usually a composite element would have other 'surrounding' markup that you need to render alongside the actual child elements themselves.

Comment: Ah, Matthew is Zend Framework. If anyone knows ZF, it's him.

Comment: Would you mind posting some code so we can provide more specific feedback?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a blog post to show you how to create one form element (an instance of Zend_Form_Element) that holds 2 input elements or more.

http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/a-zend-framwork-compount-form-element-for-dates/

You can also use subform to group more than one elements.
link: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.forms.html#zend.form.forms.subforms

```
    $subform = new Zend_Form_SubForm();
    $subform->addElement('checkbox', 'status', array(
        'decorators' => array(
            'ViewHelper',
        )
    ));
    $subform->addElement('text', 'test', array(
        'label'      => 'Text',
        'decorators' => array(
            'ViewHelper',
            'Label'
        )
    ));
    $this->addSubForm($subform, 'subformname');
```

Answer (score 3):

Personally I thought it was a lot of work to create a composite element myself.  I needed a text box and a select menu to work together and cross validate user id's to an entity owned by that user with ajax and the php code for the element, decorator, and validator was about 200 lines of code, and then a 40 line view script for using the viewHelper to render the composite element.

I followed that tutorial as well, very helpful but didn't cover everything I needed so I had to do a lot of searches.  I decided to go with the composite element because the functionality was key and used in a lot of places, but if it is just on one form, I would implement it as 2 independent elements and write simple form processing code to correlate the elements.